# Moving live() from jquery 1.4 to jquery 1.11

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
    $(".watermark").live('focus', function() {
        $tb = $(this);
        if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
            $tb.val("");
            $tb.removeClass("water");
        }
    }).live('blur', function() {
    ...
    }
    }).blur();
```

How can I upgrade/rewrite this code to take advantage of the latest jQuery features?

Here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6EKVV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.live()` is deprecated as of version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. You can use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead:

```
$(".water").addClass('watermark');
$(".watermark").on('focus', function() {
    $tb = $(this);
    if ($tb.val() == this.title) {
        $tb.val("");
        $tb.removeClass("water");
    }
}).on('blur', function() {
    $tb = $(this);
    if ($.trim($tb.val()) == "") {
        $tb.val(this.title);
        $tb.addClass("water");
    }
}).blur();
```

Comment: thanks. Any other code improvements you can suggest?

Comment: You can also consider to use `placeholder` attribute like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6EKVV/2/

Comment: is that HTML5 specific?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's supported in all major browsers and IE version >8. If you want to support old IE versions. You can use this fallback plugin: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: nice! One issue is the text looks grayed out even after user has entered text and moved to next control. How to fix that?

Comment: To test if the attrib is supported in my browser, can I use the modernizr plugin too?

Comment: Placeholder has different behaviour on different browsers. So what you describe is happen on chrome if I'm not wrong, so nothing we can do about it. For your second question, yes you can use `modernirz` to detect features supported in CSS3 and HTML5 of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You have to delegate the event on the parent element of `.watermark`.

Like:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.watermark', function() {
  //...
});
```

`$(".watermark").live('focus', callback)` is equal to  `$(document).on('focus', '.watermark', callback)`.

`$(".watermark").on('focus', callback)` is just equal to `$(".watermark").focus(callback)`, which is not what `.live` used to be.

Comment: Avoid to use event delegation when unnecessary, especially for OP's case.

Comment: @Felix Yes, but op is asking for migrate the code using `.live`.

Comment: @xdazz Yes, but using `.on()` is enough for his code to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6EKVV/1/ in jQuery version 1.11 which is his case. So I feel like event delegation is more like a helpful notes or suggestion than an answer which is unnecessary in this situation.

Comment: @Felix Then in the first place `.live` should not be used. It's just a piece of code, like a tree in a forest.